# Find names of positional arguments through introspection

Tags: python

Is there a way to figure out the names of the positional arguments to a python function?

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
  pass

f=foo
# How do I find out want the 1st argument to f is called? I want 'arg1' as an answer
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function [`inspect.getargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) does what you need in Python 2.

In Python 3, this has been deprecated, and you should instead use [`signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature).